# card.io Mono for Android (Xamarin Studio)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, card.io

Has anybody successfully created a card.io wrapper they're willing to share that can be used in a Mono for Android application or can somebody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

1. Create a new **Android Java Bindings Library** Project
2. Add the .jar and .so files from [card.io SDK 3.0.3](https://www.card.io/download/card.io-android-sdk-3.0.3.zip), be sure to use the existing folder structure
3. Add the following to Transforms/EnumMethods.xml to resolve a compiler error:

   ```
   <mapping jni-class="io/card/payment/CardIOActivity">
       <method jni-name="onActivityResult" parameter="p1" clr-enum-type="Android.App.Result" />
   </mapping>
   ```
4. Add a reference to the above Library in my main application

Everything compiles and I can access the card.io classes:

```
using IO.Card.Payment;

private void WireupScanCardButton()
{
    Log.Debug(this.GetType().Name, "WireupScanCardButton");

    this.ScanCardButton.Click += delegate 
    {
        Log.Debug(this.GetType().Name, "ScanCard.Click");

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CardIOActivity));

        // Required for authentication with card.io
        intent.PutExtra(CardIOActivity.ExtraAppToken, "<MY PRIVATE TOKEN HERE>");

        // Customize these values to suit your needs.
        intent.PutExtra(CardIOActivity.ExtraNoCamera, false);
        intent.PutExtra(CardIOActivity.ExtraSuppressManualEntry, true);
        intent.PutExtra(CardIOActivity.ExtraRequireExpiry, false);
        intent.PutExtra(CardIOActivity.ExtraRequireCvv, false);
        intent.PutExtra(CardIOActivity.ExtraRequireZip, false);

        // Run the Activity
        this.StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);            
    };
}
```

However, I am always presented with the following error:

**this device can not use camera to read card numbers**

NOTES:

- I have tried running on several different physical devices
- the card.io.jar file has a Build Action of: EmbeddedJar
- the .so files have a Build Action of: EmbeddedNativeLibrary
- I've explicitly set the **Abi** for each .so file in the Project **ItemGroup**

I'm very new to Android/Xamarin, so spend more time researching than coding.

The .so files do not appear to be in the .apk file

Edit:

The .so files do seem to get picked up by the compiler.
After compilation, if I check the **obj/Release/** folder there is a subfolder **native_library_imports** that contains the .so files in appropriate subfolders according to the supported Abi type.

However, the .so files still do not appear in the final .apk file.

logcat output:

```
04-18 08:12:20.462 D/ActivityAddPaymentSource( 5824): ScanCard.Click
04-18 08:12:20.472 E/ActivityManager(  191): exception bw.write()java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected
04-18 08:12:20.472 I/ActivityManager(  191): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.onetab.android/io.card.payment.CardIOActivity (has extras) } from pid 5824
04-18 08:12:20.472 D/PowerManagerService(  191): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch
04-18 08:12:20.492 D/ActivityAddPaymentSource( 5824): OnPause
04-18 08:12:20.492 E/Sensors (  191): GsSensor: line +83 ~~~handle===0~~en==1~~!n
04-18 08:12:20.502 E/Sensors (  191): GsSensor::setDelay: line +113 ~~~handle===0~~ns==1553152~~!n
04-18 08:12:20.502 E/Sensors (  191): GsSensor::setDelay: line +113 ~~~handle===0~~ns==-2135896001~~!n
04-18 08:12:20.542 W/card.io ( 5824): cardioScanErrorNoDeviceSupport: This device cannot use the camera to read card numbers.
04-18 08:12:20.572 E/ActivityManager(  191): exception bw.write()java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected
04-18 08:12:20.572 D/PowerManagerService(  191): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch
04-18 08:12:20.582 E/Sensors (  191): GsSensor: line +83 ~~~handle===0~~en==0~~!n
04-18 08:12:20.622 D/ActivityAddPaymentSource( 5824): OnResume
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I finally resolved this after some experimentation.

1. Follow the 4 steps in my original post
2. Extract the card.io SDK to the root of the library project so you end up with a folder structure of: **ProjectRoot/libs/`<the sdk files and abi subfolders>`**
3. Add the .jar file to the Project **Jars** folder (select the ***add a link*** option)
4. Add the **libs** folder to the root of your project (excluding the .jar file)
5. You may need to manually edit the **.csproj** file to add the **Abi** target of each **.so** file
6. Ensure the .**jar** file has a **Build action** of **EmbeddedJar**
7. Ensure the **.so** files have a **Build action** of **EmbeddedNativeLibrary**

*@tomwhipple - thanks for the contribution. I tried to upvote your answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation.*

Answer (score 4):

The Android logcat should show a more specific error message, but this problem is due to missing native libraries. (For normal Android projects these live in the `/libs` directory, with architecture specific subdirectories.)

These are the `.so` files that you mention are missing from the .apk. They contain all of the image processing logic, so card.io can't scan if they are not there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited my original post with further info. There is something about **Transport endpoint is not connected** that I'm looking into.